# Double ID tag in Materialize css Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, materialize

I am currently making a template in Joomla using Materialize CSS as the framework. I get stuck with the part where I make a dropdown menu in Joomla. The HTML should go as followed (as explained on the documentation page of Materialize)

```
<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
 <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
 <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
 <li class="divider"></li>
 <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
</ul>

<li>
 <a class="dropdown-button" href="#!"  data-activates="dropdown1">Dropdown<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
</li>
```

My index.php goes as follows:

```
<!-- Start Navbar -->
     <nav class="indigo" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-wrapper container">
            <a id="logo-container" href="index.php" class="brand-logo">
                <?php echo $logo; ?>
                    <?php if ($this->params->get('sitedescription')) : ?>
                        <?php echo '<div class="site-description">' . htmlspecialchars($this->params->get('sitedescription')) . '</div>'; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
            <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="none" />
            </ul>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
                <li class="material-menu">
                    <a href="index.php">
                        <?php echo $logo; ?>
                            <?php if ($this->params->get('sitedescription')) : ?>
                                <?php echo '<div class="site-description">' . htmlspecialchars($this->params->get('sitedescription')) . '</div>'; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>                 
                    </a>
                </li>
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" style="none" />
            </ul>
            <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi mdi-menu"></i></a>
        </div><!-- /nav-wrapper container -->
    </nav>
<!-- End Navbar -->
```

The problem is that I use the menu module twice because of the mobile menu. An ID tag can only be used once so the dropdown doesn't work.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a good idea to have the same module position duplicated in the template multiple times as it will render the same markup every time.

Instead, the best approach is to create a copy of the menu module and publish it to your mobile menu position.

- In Joomla Admin, duplicate the current menu module
- Publish the duplicated menu module to a new position e.g. "mobile-nav". All other settings for this duplicated module can be identical to the original (desktop) menu module.
- Update your template code to include position for "mobile-nav" where the mobile navigation should be displayed.

Update template code for new module position (just swap out position-1 with mobile-nav):

```
<ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
    <li class="material-menu">
        <a href="index.php">
            <?php echo $logo; ?>
                <?php if ($this->params->get('sitedescription')) : ?>
                    <?php echo '<div class="site-description">' . htmlspecialchars($this->params->get('sitedescription')) . '</div>'; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>                 
        </a>
    </li>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="mobile-nav" style="none" />
</ul>
```

Comment: Aahh of course. Thank you so much for your detailed answer!